# Upper case schema fields in DXA 2.2 issue

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, .net

For DXA 2.2 (.NET) I observed that having uppercase schema fields does not work. It seems like delivery maps them to first letter lowercase, so even though I try different types of mapping in DXA to a model, it won't bind the field unless I rename the field to lowercase in Tridion schema.

So example that does not work:

```
[SemanticEntity(EntityName = "EmbeddedLink", Prefix = "a")]
public class EmbeddedLink : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("a:LinkText")]
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
```

Schema field: **LinkText**

And this works:

```
[SemanticEntity(EntityName = "EmbeddedLink", Prefix = "a")]
public class EmbeddedLink : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("a:linkText")]
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
```

Schema field: **linkText**

So even though schema field **LinkText** is the same as mapping in the model, it does not load. Only when I rename to **linkText** is schema and in the model, it works.

**However, this worked in DXA 1.7, so my question is when did this change, why, and now to mitigate this because the upgrade to 2.2 then requires full schemas change, update and republish.**